# Mysterious text being appended to SMS Messages

Tags: email, sms, sms-gateway

I have a strange problem, which is, mysterious text is being appended to SMS messages I send out - but only in this one case it seems. The user has Sprint as their carrier.

For a, hopefully, better understanding, let me describe my environment:

I have a service that I run for my clients which sends out queued up emails from a table (the service also writes those emails to the queue in a different process). Based on predefined user settings, the writing procedure of the service adds the BODY, some other relevant data, and the TO_ADDRESS, which, can be an email address, or, the SMS email address equivalent (I have a service that gets this SMS address). That means I rely on an SMS Gateway to accomplish the actual conversion of the email to a text. Because my organization does not have its own SMS Gateway, I also rely on the individual carrier's gateways for this.

Here is an image of the problem (I blanked out user details). Notice the text after the "(from {blank} ISD)" in the last two texts, it is not ours, and, is not in our email queue - it comes from somewhere after we send the message:

[image]

Any enlightenment on this issue will be helpful. I have searched many different ways to try and find something on this already.

Thank you.